# Two isomorphism about restriction function and idempotent embedding functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, functors

I am reading the book “elements of the representation theory of associative algebras” and I have a problem about the proof of the theorem 6.8 in chapter 1.

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, $e\in A$ be a non-zero idempotent and $B=eAe$.

The functor $T_e$, $L _e:mod~B \rightarrow mod~A$ and $res _e: mod~A \rightarrow mod~B$ are defined by

$$res_e(-)=(-)e, \quad T_e(-)=-\otimes eA, \quad L_e(-)=Home_B(Ae,-)$$

where $Mod~B$ is the category of all finitely generated right $B$-modules and $Mod~A$ is the category of all finitely  generated right $A$-modules

If we choose $Y$ is a right $B$-module, the author says that there are isomorphisms $$(Y\otimes_B eA)e\cong Y\otimes_B eAe\quad(1),$$
$$(Hom_B(Ae,Y))e\cong Y_B\quad (2).$$

The first isomorphism seems natural, but I don't know how to prove it strictly.

The second isomorphism I don't seem to have any ideas about.

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the ideas. I leave to you the verification of each claim below.

For the first isomorphism, note that the map
$$
Y\times eA\to Y\otimes_B B,\quad (y,ex)\mapsto y\otimes exe
$$
is $B$-balanced, so it induces a homomorphism of $k$-vector spaces
$$
\alpha_Y':Y\otimes_B eA\to Y\otimes_B B, \quad y\otimes ex\mapsto y\otimes exe.
$$
Then define $\alpha_Y:(Y\otimes_B eA)e\to Y\otimes_B B$ by
$$
\alpha_Y((y\otimes ex)e) = \alpha_Y'(y\otimes ex),
$$
this map is a well defined $B$-module homomorphism. We can construct an inverse similarly: The map
$$
Y\times B\to (Y\otimes_B eA)e,\quad (y,exe)\mapsto (y\otimes ex)e
$$
is a well defined $B$-balanced map, and the induced $k$-linear homomorphism
$$
\beta_Y:Y\otimes_B B\to (Y\otimes_B eA)e
$$
is an inverse for $\alpha_Y$.

For the second isomorphism note that $Ae$ is a $(A,B)$-bimodule, which induces a structure of right $A$-module on $L_e(Y_B)=\mathrm{Hom}_B(Ae,Y_B)$ for all right $B$-module $Y_B$. This structure is given by
$$
(f\cdot a)(x)=f(ax)
$$
for all $x\in Ae$, $a\in A$ and $f\in \mathrm{Hom}_B(Ae,Y_B)$. Now consider the map
$$
\varphi_Y:\mathrm{Hom}_B(Ae,Y_B)e\to Y_B, \quad f\cdot e\mapsto f(e).
$$
This map is well defined and is a $B$-module homomorphism. We can construct an explicit inverse for $\varphi_Y$, namely
$$
\psi_Y:Y_B\to \mathrm{Hom}_B(Ae,Y_B)e,
$$
where for $y\in Y_B$ and $xe\in Ae$ (with $x\in A$), we define
$$
\psi_Y(y)(xe) = yexe,
$$
which shows that $\varphi_Y$ is an isomorphism of $B$-bmodules.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.